# how to count up and show database table entries Django

Tags: python, django

I am using chartsjs to generate charts.
i have set my chart labels to:

**Index.py**

```
 labels: [

  {% for number in the_numbers_from_Floating %}
      "week " + {{ number.pk }},
   {% endfor %}

],
```

**Views.py**

```
def index(request):
the_numbers_from_Floating = Floating.objects.all()

return render(request, "index.html", {
    'the_numbers_from_Floating': the_numbers_from_Floating,
                                      })
```

my problem is that i am setting my label to the `pk` of my database table. If entries are deleted and new entries are added then the `pk` value rises. hence throwing off my labels seen below in the pictures. to fix this i should set it so that i am iterating up to the `count()` of my table. but how can i do that?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define label indexes using range:

```
def index(request):

    the_numbers_from_Floating = Floating.objects.all()

    return render(request, "index.html", {
        'the_numbers_from_Floating': the_numbers_from_Floating,
        'label_indexes': range(1, the_numbers_from_Floating.count()+1)
        })
```

Then in template:

```
 labels: [

  {% for index in label_indexes %}
      "week " + {{ index }},
   {% endfor %}

],
```

Comment: Thanks, that was a big help.